# CS8121: Custom<T> cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'T'

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-7.0

Considering the following code:

```
struct Custom<T> where T : struct { }
//...
Nullable<int> x = 2;
if(x is int z) { } //compiles
Custom<int> a = 2;
if(a is int b) { } //CS8121 An expression of type 'Custom<int>' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'int'.
```

What makes possible for `Nullable<T>` to handle a pattern of `T`? Can I do the same for my custom struct? I already tried conversion operators, but with no luck. Not sure if I tried every possible operator, though.

Comment: There is more to Nullable<T>, see here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The language gives nullable types (i.e. everything of the form `Nullable<T>`) boxing and unboxing conversions, which `is` respects. There is no way to add boxing and unboxing conversions to user-defined types.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think it would be useful to have that feature. I think I'm going to open an issue in the Roslyn repository on github for further discussion about this topic.

Comment: I sincerely doubt you'll get anyone to sign off on that -- boxing is too fundamental an operation. Many parts in the language and the runtime expect it to work one particular way; mixing in user code is a recipe for disaster, if it were possible at all. But, of course, starting a discussion is free. :-) There's slightly more chance of success with getting pattern-matching `is` to respect conversion operators, I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What makes possible for `Nullable<T>` to handle a pattern of `T`?

Some compiler magic. There is no conversion operator defined which allows this to work (I have tested), it is just the compiler who knows how to pattern match `Nullable<T>` to `T`.

Comment: So the answer for the question "Can I do the same for my custom struct?" is "no"?